# I need to find a bijection

Tags: combinatorics

Let E,F two sets, $F_k=\{f \in F(E,F), Cardf(E)=k\}$ Where $F(E,F)$ is the set of maps between E and F. And $P_k(F)=\{X \in F, card(X)=k\}$

Let  $\newcommand{\application}[5]{\begin{array}[t]{lccl} #1 : & #2 & \longrightarrow & #3 \\ & #4 & \longmapsto & #5 \end{array}}$ $\application{\Phi}{F_k}{P_k(F)}{f}{f(E)}$

Let $A \in P_k(F)$ I want to find a bijection between $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ and another set to show that $A$ has $S_{n,k}$ antecedent by $\Phi$, (where $S_{n,k}=$ the number of onto maps from a set of $n$ element to another of $k$ element).

(I hope I used the correct vocabulary, I'm not used to english maths..)

Answer (score 1):

Really confusing notation, but basically $\Phi ^{-1}(A)=\{f:E\longrightarrow A: f \text{ surjective}\}.$ I am going to assume that $|E|=n.$ Suppose $\mathbb{S}_{n,k}=\{f:[n]\longrightarrow [k]: f\text{ surjective}\}$ with $|\mathbb{S}_{n,k}|=S_{n,k}.$ You are asking to give a bijective proof of the fact $|\Phi ^{-1} (A)|=|\mathbb{S}_{n,k}|=S_{n,k}.$
Consider an enumeration of $E=\{E_1,\cdots ,E_n\}$ and $A=\{A_1,\cdots ,A_k\}$ then consider the following function $\psi :\mathbb{S}_{n,k}\longrightarrow \Phi ^{-1}(A)$ such that for a function $f\in \mathbb{S}_{n,k}$ $\psi (f)(E_i)=A_{f(i)}.$
 Can you continue from here, i.e., proof that this $\psi$ is bijection?